# How to make a report parameter selection change another report parameter selection values while allowing multiselect for both of them?

Tags: sql, birt

Lets say I have a **table** with a list of **names**, such as "a, b, c" and each name has several **other** values assigned (some of the **other** values can be assigned to several/all of **names** values, example below).

Table example:
( names - other ):
a - aa
a - ab
a - ac
b - ab
b - bb
b - cb
c - ac
c - bc
c - cc

How do I make in **birt** so that I could select **names** in one parameter box and get corresponding **other** values to select for another parameter? I know it's possible to do that with cascading parameter, but that doesn't allow to have **multiselect for the first parameter**, which in our example would be **names** values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution partly here: https://forums.opentext.com/forums/developer/discussion/61283/allow-multi-value-for-cascading-parameter
and here (thanks google translate ^^): https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1402270/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/birt/birt-4-3-1-multi-value-cascade-parameters/

Steps to do:
change"\birt\webcontent\birt\ajax\ui\dialog\BirtParameterDialog.js" file contents (there is a file to download for replacement in one of the links, but in case it goes dead I'm sharing 2 snippets from it where the changes occur:

```
    __refresh_cascade_select : function( element )
{
    var matrix = new Array( );
    var m = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < this.__cascadingParameter.length; i++ )
    {
        for( var j = 0; j < this.__cascadingParameter[i].length; j++ )
        {
            var paramName = this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].name;
            if( paramName == this.__isnull )
                paramName = this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].value;
                
            if( paramName == element.id.substr( 0, element.id.length - 10 ) )
            {
                //CHANGE//
                //The two way work (String(selectedValue) or Array(SelectedValueArray))
                var l = 0;
                var isFirstElement = true;
                var selectedValue = "";
                var selectedValueArray = new Array();
                for(var test = 0; test<element.options.length;test++){
                    if(element.options[test].selected){
                        if(isFirstElement){
                            isFirstElement = false;
                            selectedValue = element.options[test].value;
                            
                        }
                        else{
                            selectedValue = selectedValue+","+element.options[test].value;
                        }
                        selectedValueArray[l] = element.options[test].value;
                        l++;
                    }
                }
                //CHANGE//
                
                var tempText = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
                var tempValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
                 
                // Null Value Parameter
                if ( tempValue == Constants.nullValue )
                {
                    this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].name = this.__isnull;
                    this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].value = paramName;
                }                   
                else if( tempValue == '' )
                {
                    if( tempText == "" )
                    {
                        var target = element;
                        target = target.parentNode;
                        var oInputs = target.getElementsByTagName( "input" );
                        if( oInputs.length >0 && oInputs[1].value != Constants.TYPE_STRING )
                        {
                            // Only String parameter allows blank value
                            alert( birtUtility.formatMessage( Constants.error.parameterNotAllowBlank, paramName ) );
                            this.__clearSubCascadingParameter( this.__cascadingParameter[i], j );
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Blank Value
                            this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].name = paramName;
                            this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].value = tempValue;                              
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Blank Value
                        this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].name = paramName;
                        this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].value = tempValue;
                    }                       
                }
                else
                {
                    this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].name = paramName;
                    //CHANGE//
                    //The two way work (String(selectedValue) or Array(SelectedValueArray))
                    this.__cascadingParameter[i][j].value = selectedValueArray;
                    //CHANGE//
                }
                
                for( var m = 0; m <= j; m++ )
                {
                    if( !matrix[m] )
                    {
                        matrix[m] = {};
                    }
                    matrix[m].name = this.__cascadingParameter[i][m].name;
                    matrix[m].value = this.__cascadingParameter[i][m].value;
                }
                this.__pendingCascadingCalls++;
                birtEventDispatcher.broadcastEvent( birtEvent.__E_CASCADING_PARAMETER, matrix );
            }
        }
    }
},
```

and this:

```
// exist select control and input text/password
        // compare the parent div offsetTop
        if( oFirstITC.parentNode && oFirstST.parentNode )
        {
            // Bugzilla 265615: need to use cumulative offset for special cases
            // where one element is inside a group container
            var offsetITC = Position.cumulativeOffset( oFirstITC );
            var offsetST = Position.cumulativeOffset( oFirstST );
            
            // compare y-offset first, then x-offset to determine the visual order
            if( ( offsetITC[1] > offsetST[1] ) || ( offsetITC[1] == offsetST[1] && offsetITC[0] > offsetST[0] ) )
            {
                oFirstST.focus( );              
            }
            else
            {
                oFirstITC.focus( );
            }
        }
```

After .js is changed cascading parameters can have multiselect on all levels.
Example:
1st DataSet "DS_country" query:

```
select CLASSICMODELS.OFFICES.COUNTRY
from CLASSICMODELS.OFFICES
```

2nd DataSet "DS_office" query:

```
select CLASSICMODELS.OFFICES.OFFICECODE
from CLASSICMODELS.OFFICES
where CLASSICMODELS.OFFICES.COUNTRY IN ('DS_country')
```

After datasets are created we can make cascading report parameters CRP_country and CRP_office (keep in mind that UI doesn't let you to choose "Allow multiple values" on the upper levels, but we can change that in property editor after the parameters are made by going to advanced tab and changing "Scalar parameter type" property value to "Multi Value")

The only thing left is to pick lower level cascading parameters (CRP_office in our example) and go to script tab and add this on "beforeOpen":

```
// Do that if your selections are in String type.
var stringArray = params["CRP_country"].value.toString().split(",");
var result = "";
for(var i =0 ; i < stringArray.length ; i++){
    if(i==0){
        result = "'"+stringArray[i]+"'";
    }
    else{
        result = result+",'"+stringArray[i]+"'";
    }
}

// For String
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("'DS_country'", result);

//For integer (the first part is useless)
//this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("'DS_country'", 
params["CRP_country"].value);
```